# Postgresql log_truncate_on_rotation doesn't work

Tags: postgresql

logging_collector = `on`
log_directory = `/var/log/postgresql`
log_filename = `postgresql-%a.log`
log_file_mode = `0600`
log_truncate_on_rotation = `on`
log_rotation_age = `1440`
log_rotation_size =`0`

and permissions

`rw-r-----  1 postgres postgres    0 Nov 29 00:00 postgresql-Tue.log`
`rw-r-----  1 postgres postgres 1001 Nov 29 00:00 postgresql-Tue.log.1`
`rw-r-----  1 postgres postgres    0 Nov 30 00:00 postgresql-Wed.log`
`rw-r-----  1 postgres postgres  359 Nov 30 00:00 postgresql-Wed.log.1`

What should I do?

I have changed permisions,log_file_mode parameters,log_rotation_size,log_rotation_age and still doesn't work

Comment: I won't look at that unless you remove the images and use formatted text instead.

Comment: Take a look after you `SELECT pg_reload_conf()`?

Comment: I have already tried reload_conf and restart. It wont works.

Comment: Can anyone help me?